# View restricted to a specific taxonomy term

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I have a custom content type called Property with taxonomy term fields set up for example for vocabularies Train Station, Style, and Area.

I would like to create a view showing only those Properties with a specific term within the taxonomy for example only the ones with the term London Bridge in the Train Station vocabulary.

I assumed this would be Filter Criteria in the view, however the only related option I can see is Content:Has taxonomy term which brings in all Properties that has Train Station - but I cant see how I can add the extra filter of only London Bridge within Train Station

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you clarify what vocabularies you have and what terms you have in those vocabularies. You can always ctrl-click terms in the term list to add more than one filter, but if you're looking for something more dynamic than building several views one by one by hand, you would likely be using contextual filters. There are many possibilities there, so you need to explain in more detail what it is you're trying to do.

Comment: I have a content type called property, and a term reference field called Train Station.= which calls upon the taxonomy Train Station. By example the Taxonomy calls in 2 terms London Bridge and Victoria. I am trying to create 2 pages - 1 which pulls in teasers of all properties in Victoria and 1 with London Bridge. These will be fixed landing pages showing properties for each and eventually will have a block at the top with unique copy for each page

Comment: If you go to admin/structure/taxonomy/property you get a list of all the terms as links to each term's teaser listing, like taxonomy/term/1 so the basic version is already in there, in core. If you want more control, you can clone the Taxonomy term view that comes with Views module, and modify that.

Comment: No at all. I edited your question heavily, please check it. I also put in answer, trying to answer just what you asked, realizing that what you eventually want to build will be more.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand the question correctly - potentially the easiest way to achieve this is to add a 'Term Reference' field to your 'Property' content type.

This needs to point at the taxonomy 'Train Station', and you can have multiple term references if you need other terms to describe properties.

You can then use this term reference field as a view filter. You'll be looking for **"Content:term_reference_field_name"** as opposed to "**Content:Has taxonomy term**" This will allow you to filter on a particular taxonomy term.

Good luck!

Comment: I have train station as a term reference field for property, and what you suggest sounds like it should work, however in Filter Criteria 'Content:term_reference_field_name' does not come up as an option. Any ideas?

Comment: by adding a relationship - Content: Tags (field_tags) i get other options and have added the filter Taxonomy term: Term (= London Bridge), a page is create but shows an empty page - I can confirm that I have properties with this Taxonomy though

Comment: Cracked it, thanks - I was using the wrong relationship

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is very basic functionality in Drupal. By default, if you go to a term's page, for example taxonomy/term/1, what you get is indeed a teaser list for all nodes that have that term.